# jsfiddle angularjs binding not working

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I create a jsfiddle page:

[jquery datatable with Angularjs - individual column searching](https://jsfiddle.net/hoogw/a48Le2ws/12/)

all the angularjs binding not work, it shows

```
{{n1}}
```

which should show the actual binding content.

the external resource angularjs, cdn URL seems does not working.

Answer (score 0):

the external resource angularjs cdn url does not work,

you must click javascipt setting, then choose framework & extensions, as angularjs

see screen shot

[image]